# I'm getting a KeyError while trying to redirect to homepage in Django framework

Tags: python, django, django-views, keyerror

From my views.py, in this class given below

```
class Home(TemplateView):

    model_name = AccountInfo
    template_name = "BudgetApp/Home.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.session["username"]
        context={}
        context["user"] = user
        return render(request,self.template_name,context)
```

Apparently, I'm getting a key error:'username'. Could you please help me out on this?
This is probably the main reason why it doesn't redirect to the homepage after login for me.

Comment: request.session.get("username") - this will get rid of key error. However value will be null. Can you supply code where username is added to session?

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
request.user
```

It will return a User object if is authenticated and a AnonymousUser if it isn't.
Something like:

```
If request.user.is_authenticated:
     context["user"]=request.user
```

Read more about in Django Docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.user

Comment: Thanks a lot! Will try it now!!

Answer (score 0):

Replace with following code ll resolve your KeyError.

```
class Home(TemplateView):

    model_name = AccountInfo
    template_name = "BudgetApp/Home.html"

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user = request.session.get("username")
        context={}
        if user:
            context["user"] = user
        return render(request,self.template_name,context)
```